# Loading page in Windows Phone 8.1 with async method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to display a loding circle bar, while a page in Windows Phone is loading. The latency is due to an async method, which donwloads a Json file and concert it to List of objects. Is it a problem, if the async method is in another Class ? Also, how Can I get back the result of aysnc method in another class/page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your code in separate class

```
public class Result 
{
   public string Message {get;set}
}
public class Utility
{
   public async Task<Result> GetJson()
   {
       //do something here
       return result;
   }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
LoadingIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
await Utility.GetJson()
LoadingIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

And add this to your page XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Other UI elements -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="LoadingIndicator" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock Text="Loading..."/>
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Good reply ! That's what I was looking for ! About the circle waiting bar, how Can I do ? I want to show something to wait for the user !

Comment: show loading message before you call await Utility.GetJson()

Comment: That's I got. My  is how can I show something like a circle bar to the user, I mean as layout structure.

Comment: You can use ProgressRing

Comment: Thank you again for your support. If I want to add some text, like "Loading...", how can I do ?